# How to Customize the empty Keys in a Numeric Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I need to provide an option for the user to switch to AlphaNumeric Keyboard from the Numeric keyboard below, i was thinking can i make use of the empty keys in the numeric Keyboard and customize it with say `abc` so it can switch to alphanumeric keyboard.

[image: Numeric Keyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to make your own implementation of a keyboard, the only way to control it's appearance is via the [InputType](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Type) of your EditText.

**You simply can't modify any buttons of the system keyboard.** It will look different depending on the manufacturer anyways.

Here's what you could do:

- Change the InputType (for the EditText that needs alphanumeric input or via a toggle button or...)
- Implement your own keyboard for your specific needs

Comment: Adding a toggle button is the problem. i have implemented an relative layout which stands above the keyboard with a `ABC` button and on click of that set the input type.  but i m looking to see if there are other options other than writing my own keyboard view.